# In Coq, `Export`, `Require`, and filtered_import do not work well

Tags: coq

In Coq, `Export`, `Require`, and filtered_import do not work well.

I made `_CoqProject`.

```
-R theories/ Library_Name

theories/A/B.v
theories/A.v
theories/C.v
```

I made `theories/A/B.v`.

```
Definition foo : _ := _.
```

I made `theories/A.v`.

```
Require Library_Name.A.B.
Export Library_Name.A.B (foo).

Definition baa : _ := _.
```

I made `theories/C.v`.

```
Require Library_Name.A.
Import Library_Name.A (baa).

Definition baz : _ := A.foo.
```

However, `coqc` said it could not find `A.foo` on `theories/C.v`.

What I want to hear is how to refer to `A.B.foo` as `A.foo`, which is better than redefining it in `A`.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such thing as filtered import in Coq (see the [documentation of Require](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html?highlight=require#compiled-files)).

Comment: I had mistakenly assumed that filtered import was available in `Require Import`/`Require Export` as well. `Import`/`Export` do have filtered import ([the document of Import](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/modules.html#coq:cmd.Import)).

Comment: `Require Import` and `Require Export` do support filters: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:cmd.Require says "From dirpath? Require  Import ​ Export  import_categories?? filtered_import+"

Answer (score 1):

Your desire is reasonable, but not how `Export` works.  What you want amounts to a "filtered `Include`", not a "filtered `Export`".

When you write `Export Library_Name.A.B (foo).`, this says "when the current module is `Import`ed, also make the unqualified `foo` available".  It does not change the qualified name of `foo`, which is still `Library_Name.A.B.foo`.

You can do something like

```
Notation foo := Library_Name.A.B.foo (only parsing).
```

in `A.v`, and then you'll get `A.foo`.  Or, if `Include` gets support for filtering (consider submitting a feature request for this?), you could write `Include Library_Name.A.B (foo)` (except that this syntax conflicts with inclusion of module functor applications...)